# python beautifulsoup giving specific part of table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image: giving][image: expecting]

```
page = requests.get("http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019")
c = page.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
tables=soup.find_all("table",{"style":"width: 500px;"})
print(tables)
```

In this page there are 10 tables. but it is giving only specific part of table instead of completre table.
it is giving all table not completely.
i am expecting like second table . but coming like first screenshot

Comment: What part is missing?

Comment: just do soup.find_all("table")

Comment: yes i am doing the same.. first <tr> is only coming from table

Comment: What's the output you are getting and what's the output you expect?, Could you post those things?

Comment: please check the screnshot.. m expecting second one but giving first one..

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you to post the html code too, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: i have shared the url .. please check this.. tables

Comment: url is on my code

Comment: can you explain How you extract the output you save directly to a file ?

Comment: no i am uding HttpResponse in django.http so directly it is showing in browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is giving 14 entries, out of which first one and last one shouldnt be considered. Last one being javascript code.

You just need to change the parser to a more lenient one, more can be found here https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser.

```
page = requests.get("http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019")
c = page.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html5lib")
tables=soup.find_all("table")

for table in tables[1:-1]:
      print (table.text)
```

If changing your parser shows you an error, install html5lib in your environment, like this
    pip3 install html5lib

Comment: hi bro. i have done the same way you have done.. but it is coming like my first screenshot i have shared . please have a look into this.. giving some part of table

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: yes bro its working.. could u please tell me what u have changed??

Comment: but why html5lib instead??

Comment: Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document,  html5lib parser, which parses HTML the way a web browser does.

Comment: Please chek again, the above code works fine and it has 14 table entries in tables.